# Desabilitar collapse bootstrap v4 laravel 5.5

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

tudo bem?

Para esta minha duvida, já encontrei solução para bootstrap 3 mas para o 4 não.

Procurei em diversas páginas, aqui no 'stack', busquei modificar o css e nada.

Alguém pode ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua resposta está na documentação!

> Para `navbars` que nunca colapsam, adicione a classe `.navbar-expand` na barra de navegação. Para `navbars` que sempre colapsam, não adicione nenhuma classe `.navbar-expand`.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue um exemplo funcionando. Essa Navbar sempre vai ficar "aberta" ela nunca vai recolher os Links dentro desse botão

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Olá amigo, obrigado. Ao ver sua resposta, fui ver meu codigo. Ele estava desta forma: navbar-expand-lg. Ao remover o "-lg", deu tudo certo. Obrigado.

Comment: @ShBr isso ai mesmo, esse LG significa que abaixo telas Large ele colapsa a navbar :) []´s